# no instance of function template "ThreadPool::enqueue" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (void *(*)(void *Arg), void *)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, threadpool

I am writing code for threadpool and after compiling it give me error

no instance of function template `ThreadPool::enqueue` matches the argument list -- argument types are: (void *(shih_tzu::AuthCtl::AuthController::*)(void *Arg), void *)

Threadpool.h

```
template<typename F, typename...Args>
auto ThreadPool::enqueue(F&& f, Args&&... args) -> std::future<decltype(f(args...))>
  {
    std::function<decltype(f(args...))() > func = std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto task_ptr = std::make_shared < std::packaged_task<decltype(f(args...))()>>(func);
    std::function<void() > wrapper_func = [task_ptr]()
    {
      (*task_ptr)();
    };
    mTasks.emplace(wrapper_func);
     debugLog->PrintLog("Inside Thread pool enqueue function insert new function call\n");
    cv.notify_one();
    return task_ptr->get_future();
  }
```

Calling enqueue

```
thread_pool->enqueue(&AuthController::WorkerFunction,(void *)sThreadStruct1); //error here
```

WorkerFunction signature:-

```
void* AuthController::WorkerFunction(void *Arg)
```

please help me to resolve this compile-time issue.

Comment: Could you share more about the error message you are seeing?

Comment: template<class F, class... Args> auto ThreadPool::enqueue(F &&f, Args &&...args)->std::future<decltype((f(args...)))>
no instance of function template "ThreadPool::enqueue" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (void *(shih_tzu::AuthCtl::AuthController::*)(void *Arg), void *) -- object type is: ThreadPool

Comment: So wait, you're calling notify_one but the shared memry hasnt been changed under a lock? do yourself a favor, just use something that someone else wrote.

Comment: is WorkerFunction a static function?

Comment: I am having an issue with at compile time enqueue function is working fine.i just need to build my code.

Comment: worker function is not static

Comment: `&AuthController::WorkerFunction` creates a pointer-to-member-function, those are a weird and hard to work with.  See https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members for more info.

Comment: thread_pool->enqueue(&AuthController::WorkerFunction,(void *)sThreadStruct1); //error here   Please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: @gocampus change WorkerFunction to static and it should work - but I have not checked it. Currently you are passing a pointer to member function - if that is your intention then you should also pass instance of class - otherwise how your enqueue method will know which instance to call this member function on.

Comment: @marcinj can we call a function without making it static and function is present in the same class from where I am calling can you please give me one example.

Comment: @gocampus example: thread_pool->enqueue(std::bind(&AuthController::WorkerFunction, this),(void *)sThreadStruct1);

Comment: @marcinj still getting same error `no instance of function template "ThreadPool::enqueue" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (std::_Bind<void *(shih_tzu::AuthCtl::AuthController::*(shih_tzu::AuthCtl::AuthController *))(void *Args)>, void *) -- object type is: ThreadPool`

Comment: @gocampus then try with lambda: enqueue([=] (auto p) mutable {this->WorkerFunction(p);},(void *)sThreadStruct1);

Comment: bind version should also work, but it needs placeholder for a parameter: enqueue(std::bind(&AuthController::WorkerFunction, this, std::placeholders::_1),(void *)sThreadStruct1);